# Equality Filter in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing a Spark Structured Streaming job and I have to filter on a string column.

When I am filtering on the long column it is able to filter(using below code):

```
arr =  arr.filter(col("epoch") > 1610913720)
```

But when I am doing on a string, data is not filtered:

```
arr =  arr.filter(col("id").equalTo("z12"))
```